# Socket.IO: connection to a non-existing namespace

Tags: node.js, socket.io

First post, i'll try to be as clear as possible :)

I'm trying to create on Demand namespaces on my SocketIO/NodeJS App.
Basically, the server create a specific namespace for each client.
I need to handle, server side, the case where the client try accessing a non-existing namespace.
The idea is to avoid any unwanted connection server-side, or at least, handle it to force the disconnection.

But while testing, it seems that when i try this, on client Side :

```
var socket = io("thisNameSpaceDontExist");
socket.on('connect', function(){
  window.console.log('connected to server');
})
```

The 'connect' event won't trigger, which seems perfect !
Doing a console.log on `socket`, it displays this:

```
  connected: false
  disconnected: true
```

But the main problem, is that, Server Side, it's different, there is an active connection...
While doing some research, i found this issue https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/issues/1867, still, i'm on the last version at this time: 1.3.5

for information, the socketIOHandler code i'm using:
        io.on('connection', function (socket) {
          console.log("[SocketIOHandler::Connection] +1");

```
      socket.on('disconnect', function () {
      console.log("[SocketIOHandler::Disconnection] -1");
      });
    });
```

PS:
Also find some issues and MR claiming the support of dynamic namespaces: https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/issues/1854, but these are not merged, so i don't really understand the behavior on my code...

Thank you!

Comment: Hi there, have you find a solution yet?  I'm having the same problem, and in my testing I found the 'rouge connection' seems to be preventing further connection to valid namespaces.

Comment: @PaulL, I handled the problem differently (not a clean way) , but I would be very interested if you come up with a solution